# asksavesfile writes csv with break spaces after each row

Tags: csv, tkinter

I am using `asksaveasfile` to save a dataframe (named `window.current_list`) to a CSV, and all is well except the file saves with extra blank rows in between each record. Below is the code and I have attached a pic showing the saved CSV file. Any ideas/thoughts?

Thank you much in advance!

```py
def save_file():
    """"""
    f = asksaveasfile(initialfile=window.file_name,
                      defaultextension=".csv")
    if f:
        window.current_list.to_csv(f, index=False)
        f.close()
```

[image: pic of example csv file]

Comment: Use `asksaveasfilename()` instead, or add `mode="wb"` in `asksaveasfile(...)`, or add `lineterminator="\n"` in `.to_csv(...)`.